# Side-by-side error using COM server, C++ redistributable installed

Tags: com, visual-studio-2005, windows-7-x64, side-by-side

I have an awkward situation in which I have a 32-bit lib that must be used in a x64 application.  To solve this problem I have created a COM server application to handle communication between the 32-bit and 64-bit processes.

Everything is built in VS2005 on Windows 7, version `8.0.50727.867`.  One thing I noticed is that my version does not match up with the SP1 redist version (`8.0.50727.762`).  I am thinking that this is due to the Vista update for VS2005 as I cannot find a later version of the redist.

It works on my dev machine, but it does not on my Win7 x64 box.  The error is thus:

> Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files\ScanScope\Controller\ACBarOmniServer.exe". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6195" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

Prior to this I had installed the VS2005 C++ redistributable package.  I tried installing it again, no luck.  I rummaged through my Winsxs folder and, sure enough, the version is missing.

When I run the redist installer from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5638) I get the following versions of the CRT in my sxs folder:

- 8.0.50727.42
- 8.0.50727.762
- 8.0.50727.4053
- 8.0.50727.4940

Of course, I need version `8.0.50727.6195`.

I have set everything I can to link statically (i.e., /MT, static link to MFC, no link to ATL), but something else depends on teh dynamic version of the C runtime.

I have used sxstrace with no luck.  I start the trace, launch my program, get the error, end the trace, and parse it into a different file.  The parsed file is completely empty.

One interesting thing to note; when I run the redist installer on the Win7 box it completes in literally a second or two and disappears.  Now, I do see it installed in Add/Remove programs and it does add folders to the sxs folder, but this struck me as odd.

If anyone has any experience with this help would be much appreciated.  If you need any info that I have left out please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the correct redistributable patch [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26347).

This was an update sent to VS2005 users, but not to the general public.  *sigh*, oh well.